# Load d3 map error

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I'm trying to load this [map](https://bl.ocks.org/MariellaCC/0055298b94fcf2c16940) in d3. I copied the code directly and I took the data from [here](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/MariellaCC/8dea97c0f61429d1b72a/raw/ddcb2714ac5483b948c59729187d41603e81829a/ne_50m_admin_0_countries_simplified.json) and saved it to a file named countries.json but when I start up a local server I get the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
>       at bind (d3.v3.js:842)
>       at Array.d3_selectionPrototype.data (d3.v3.js:900)
>       at Object. (map.html:86)
>       at Object.event (d3.v3.js:504)
>       at XMLHttpRequest.respond (d3.v3.js:1946)

Why am I getting this error?

This is the code

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <title>Mercator projection</title>
            <script src="//d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
            <script src="//d3js.org/topojson.v1.min.js"></script>
            <style type="text/css">


                svg {
                    background-color: white;
                }

                h1 {
                    color: rgb(115, 115, 115);
                    font-size: 18px;
                    font-family: sans-serif;
                    font-weight: bold;
                    margin: 0;
                    padding-bottom: 10px;

                }

                    #container {
                    width: 800px;
                    margin-left: auto;
                    margin-right: auto;
                    margin-top: 20px;
                    padding: 20px;
                    background-color: white;
                    box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 2px rgb(217, 217, 217);
                }

                path:hover {
                    fill: rgba(8, 81, 156, 0.2);
                    cursor:pointer;
                }



            </style>
        </head>
        <body>


        <div id="container">
            <h1>World map centered on European countries</h1>

        </div>


            <script type="text/javascript">



                //Width and height
                var w = 800;
                var h = 600;

                //Define map projection


                var projection = d3.geo.mercator()
                                       .center([ 13, 52 ])
                                       .translate([ w/2, h/2 ])
                                       .scale([ w/1.5 ]);

                //Define path generator
                var path = d3.geo.path()
                                 .projection(projection);


                //Create SVG
                var svg = d3.select("#container")
                            .append("svg")
                            .attr("width", w)
                            .attr("height", h);

                //Load in GeoJSON data
                d3.json("countries.json", function(error,collection) {
                    if(error) throw error;

                    //Bind data and create one path per GeoJSON feature
                    svg.selectAll("path")
                       .data(collection.features)
                       .enter()
                       .append("path")
                       .attr("d", path)
                       .attr("stroke", "rgba(8, 81, 156, 0.2)")
                       .attr("fill", "rgba(8, 81, 156, 0.6)");

                });



            </script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Well, you said, you saved your file as `countries.json`, but your code tries to load `europe.json`. And your callback is missing the `error` parameter. This should be `d3.json("europe.json", function(error, collection) {` instead.

Comment: I just fixed that and now I get a new error which I updated in the post.

Comment: What is `collection.features`? Error seems to be pointing to the `.data` call. Have you tried printing things out to the console to see if you are getting what you expect?

Comment: I believe collection refers to the json FeatureCollection object from the data and collection.features gets every feature from the collection. I'm relatively new to d3 and javascript so I don't really know the debugging strategies, could you give me an example of what I should print out?

Comment: The data from your json (second link) is broken. Just scroll to the bottom and you'll see.

Comment: yea the data was broken. I found another geo json file and the map shows up now.